# How do I send a raw TCP request from jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

There is the excellent "httpRequest" I can use in a pipeline build step.

But now I want to send a raw TCP request, I could not find a plugin for this. Is there a supported plugin feature for this? I want to avoid shelling out for this.

This is an example of the raw TCP request I am making:

```
echo 'abc123 blahblahblah' | nc public.endpoint.com 10514
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your command in [sh](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-sh-%20shell%20script). This will execute shell command on Jenkins `node` that you specified.

```
sh 'echo \'abc123 blahblahblah\' | nc intake.logs.datadoghq.com 10514'
```

Comment: Don't want to Shell out for this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned info about shelling. Unfortunately, Jenkins don't have any plugins for it. And using `sh` is normal case